# zcat failing in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, zabbix, zcat

I am trying to import the schema it is failing , please suggest me to solve this error

```
- name: Import the initial schema
  command: zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.5/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix

TASK: [zabbix-server | Import the initial schema] *****************************
failed: [10.100.140.120] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["zcat", "/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.2.5/create.sql.gz", "|", "mysql", "-u", "zabbix", "-p", "zabbix",   "zabbix"], "delta": "0:00:00.003563", "end": "2017-05-01 11:03:46.004996", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-05-01 11:03:46.001433", "warnings": []}
stderr: gzip: invalid option -- 'u'
Try `gzip --help' for more information.
```

My log shows that zabbix.users does not exist

```
3862:20170501:112105.959 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
  3862:20170501:112105.962 [Z3005] query failed: [1146] Table 'zabbix.users' doesn't exist [select userid from users limit 1]
  3862:20170501:112105.962 cannot use database "zabbix": database is not a Zabbix database
  3913:20170501:112116.213 Starting Zabbix Server. Zabbix 3.2.5 (revision 67445).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible's `command` module does not support shell `|` pipes or things like it, only simple commands and arguments.  You'd need to use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) or even better, [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) the create.sql.gz file over to the host then use the [mysql_db module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_db_module.html) which features `state: import`.